# calling sizeof on a function call skips actually calling the function!}

Tags: c++, sizeof

I happened to stumble across this piece of code.

```
int x(int a){
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    return a + 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(x(20))<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to print 20 followed 4. But it just prints 4. Why does it happen so? Isn't it incorrect to optimize out a function, that has a side effect (printing to IO/file etc)?

Comment: The code does not call the function&mdash;it does not even manipulate a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator, and the operand is never evaluated.

Comment: Thanks! But as we can see x() has a side effect of printing to the IO stream. Wouldn't it be wrong to not call the function because we just know the sizeof's value at compile time?

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath: It doesn't matter what the function does. `sizeof` is specifically designed to avoid any and all side-effects the expression might have.

Comment: More importantly, the language standard expressedly says that the operand of `sizeof` is _not_ evaluated.  (This is very important in some metaprogramming techniques, where the "called" function doesn't even exist.)

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is actually an operator and it is evaluated in compile-time.

The compiler can evaluate it because the size of the return type of `x` is fixed; it cannot change during program execution.

Answer (score 2):

result of sizeof is computed in compiling time in C++. so there has of function call to x(20)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof()` gives the size of the datatype. In your case it doesn't need to call the function to obtain the datatype.

I suspect sizeof also does it's business at compile time rather than runtime...

Answer (score 2):

Let me quote c++03 standard, #5.3.3.

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   **which is not evaluated**, or a parenthesized type-id.